# Name generator specific first letter

Tags: php

I created a name generator that works fine but now I would like for the results of my random words to start by a specific letter let's say "S" so all the results will always start by the letter "S".

Here is my code so far :

```
<?php
function getRandomWord($len = 7) {
  $word = array ( "exemple" ,"1");
  shuffle($word);
  return substr(implode($word), 0, $len);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
  echo getRandomWord(). "\n";
}
```

Thanks!

My code works fine, I just don't know how to force it to be created by a certain letter as a first letter.

Comment: It was just basic string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
function getRandomWord($len = 7, $start = 'S') {
  $word = array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'));
  shuffle($word);
  $word = $start . substr(implode($word), 0, $len - 1);
  return $word;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
  echo getRandomWord() . "<br>";
}
```

// output

```
SgmIuSb
SWpYANu
SxRqWBt
SvYpOQb
SPQlWfJ
SvUjmbM
SjxUmYv
SBaPxEd
SzYrqVU
SLojCPs
SwFRCSv
SiCpkxo
SmDdaGL
SSLcilq
SXQoLkr
SnHZAUE
SuaIszy
SyJGwlO
Svdbijp
SSXHUOp
SpeMAuv
SgtpTBi
SmoLstC
SaGtlHR
SEABDCs
SdDphmZ
SAHwquP
SRANhwe
SBmwRgU
SMHXYQL
```

just pass the character in `$start` parameter that you want.